# WCF binding extension for message compression

Tags: wcf, binding, compression

I'm trying to add message compression to my WCF service, but I'm kind of stuck...

So far I have:

1. An implementation of MessageEncoder:

   ```
   public class CompressionEncoder : MessageEncoder  
   {

       public CompressionEncoderFactory _factory;  
       public const string GZipContentType = "application/x-gzip";

       public override string ContentType
       {
           get
           {
               return GZipContentType;
           }
       }

       public override string MediaType
       {
           get { return ContentType; }
       }

       public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
       {
           get { return _factory.MessageVersion; }
       }

       public CompressionEncoder(CompressionEncoderFactory factory)
       {
           _factory = factory;
       }

       public override Message ReadMessage(Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders,     string contentType)
       {
           var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress, false);
           XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(decompressedStream);
           Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(reader, maxSizeOfHeaders, _factory.MessageVersion);
           msg.Properties.Encoder = this;
           return msg;
       }

       public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
       {
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count);
           GZipStream decompressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
           return ReadMessage(decompressedStream, int.MaxValue);
       }

       public override void WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
       {
           GZipStream compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true);
           XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(compressedStream);
           message.WriteMessage(writer);
       }

       public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
       {
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
           GZipStream compressedStream = new GZipStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true);
           XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(compressedStream);
           message.WriteMessage(writer);
           writer.Close();

           int messageLength = (int)compressedStream.Length;
           byte[] messageBytes = new byte[messageLength];
          compressedStream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageLength);

           int totalLength = messageLength + messageOffset;
           byte[] totalBytes = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(totalLength);
           Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);

           ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);
           return byteArray;
       }

   }
   ```
2. An implementation of MessageEncoderFactory:

   ```
   public class CompressionEncoderFactory : MessageEncoderFactory
   {
       CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement _element;

       public CompressionEncoderFactory(CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement element)
       {
           _element = element;
       }

       public override MessageEncoder Encoder
       {
           get { return new CompressionEncoder(this); }
       }

       public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
       {
           get { return _element.MessageVersion; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. An implementation of MessageEncodingBindingElement:

   ```
   public sealed class CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement : MessageEncodingBindingElement 
   {
       MessageVersion _messageVersion = MessageVersion.None;

       public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory()
       {
           return new CompressionEncoderFactory(this);
       }

       public override MessageVersion MessageVersion
       {
           get
           {
               return _messageVersion;
           }
           set
           {
               _messageVersion = value;
           }
       }

       public override BindingElement Clone()
       {
           return new CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement();
       }
   }
   ```
4. An implementation of BindingElementExtensionElement:

   ```
   public class CompressionBindingElementExtensionElement : BindingElementExtensionElement
   {
       public override Type BindingElementType
       {
           get { return typeof(CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement); }
       }

       protected override System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElement      CreateBindingElement()
       {
           return new CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement();
       }
   }
   ```
5. In the web.config I added this:

   ```
   <service name="MyService">
       <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CompressionBinding" contract="IMyService" />
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
   ...
   <bindings>
     <customBinding>
       <binding name="CompressionBinding">
         <messageCompression />
         <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous"></httpTransport>
       </binding>
     </customBinding>
   </bindings>
   ...
   <extensions>
     <bindingElementExtensions>
       <add name="messageCompression" type="MyNamespace.CompressionBindingElementExtensionElement, MyNamespace" />
     </bindingElementExtensions>
   </extensions>
   ```

---

But when I run a client and call some service code, I get the following error:

```
The message version of the outgoing message (EnvelopeNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none) AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not match that of the encoder (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)). Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the HTTP compression feature of any decent Web server?

Comment: Hm, didn't know about that... tnx, that should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `MessageVersion _messageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10;` at (3.).
Look at the Microsoft Technology Sample "TechnologySamples\Extensibility\MessageEncoder\Compression\".